# c# mongodb find array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i want to retrieve an array of objects in my document. In the shell i use this:

`db.products.findOne({ProductId : 1}).Seller`

In C# this is the structure of my classes

```
public class Product
{
    public double ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public List<Seller> Seller { get; set; }
}

public class Seller
{
    public double SellerId { get; set; }
    public string SellerName { get; set; }
}
```

What is the equivalent command in mongodb.net driver?

`db.products.findOne({ProductId : 1}).Seller`

I expect the Output to be :

```
[
    {
        "SellerId" : 123,
        "SellerName" : "ABC"
    },
    {
        "SellerId" : 345,
        "SellerName" : "MGJ"
    }
]
```

Please see attached image [output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMOLu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Projection. Here is how you do it:

```
public List<BsonDocument> GetSellers(double productId)
{
    var context = new Context();
    var filter = Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ProductId, productId);
    var project = Builders<Product>.Projection.Include(x => x.Sellers);
    var sellers = context.Product.Find(filter).Project(project).ToList();
    return sellers;
}
```

Note that a I changed `Seller` to `Sellers` since it is a list. I would also use `ObjectId` for the ids (instead of `double` or any other type).

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<Product> GetProduct(double productId)
{
    return await FindOneAsync(p => (p.ProductId == productId));
}
```

Comment: this will get the desired product by its Id, is there a way to fetch only the array of seller as in the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

```
db1.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { ProductId: 1 }
    },{ $unwind: "$Seller" }, {
        $group: {
            _id: '$ProductId',
            SELLER: { $push: {SellerId: $SellerId, SellerName: $SellerName } }
        }  },  {
        $project:
        {
            _id: "$_id",
            SELLER: '$SELLER'
        }
    }]).toArray()
    .then(result => res.json(result))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
```

I use mongoCLient. Try to use `aggregate` `group` and `project` for getting desired output..
Hope this helps